# JavaFX Scene Builder Passing Paramters before the window opens

Tags: java, javafx, parameters, fxml

I am trying to pass a string to the next window so when it loads it will show the data retrieved from the database, based on that string.

I have run into an issue where it will only set the string AFTER the window has loaded and it has attempted to fill the data out from the database so I am always left with an empty table.

I hardcoded the string in to make sure my function that pulls and prints the data is correct and it is its working so that leaves me the issue where I am passing the string from the previous screen to the next.

This is my code

```
    Stage app_stage =(Stage) ((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLMenu.fxml"));
    Parent menuPage_parent = loader.load();
    FXMLMenuController menuCon = loader.<FXMLMenuController>getController();
    usernametoPass = usernameField.getText();
    menuCon.setUname(usernametoPass); //THIS is the function that sets the string

    Scene menuPage_scene = new Scene(menuPage_parent);
    app_stage.hide();
    app_stage.setScene(menuPage_scene);
    app_stage.show();
```

Now using this on load by printing the string I always get null because its not set. However if I print the string AFTER the load(via button press) it shows the correct string.

Is there a way to set it before it loads?

Comment: Either set the controller in code (instead of specifying the controller class in FXML), or use a controller factory. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml/14190310#14190310